# iOS6: How to connect UIViewController in Storyboard via Identifier?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, storyboard, ios6

Does anyone already know how to connect UIViewControllers in Storyboard with the identifier? It does not seem to work anymore..

Comment: Perhaps you mean UIViewController?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select the UIViewController, once u see a highlighted UIView (usually blue color) then go to the left most column on the XCODE. Select the Attribute inspector , you will see "Title" and "Identifier" label in the "View Controller" section. Give any name to it and in the program to refer to your view controller you can do something like this:

```
UIStoryboard *us = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstview"];
```

This works , let me know if u have any issues.

Comment: Ok, in a new project it works well. I think it's an xcode error.